# Unable to run any command inside a rails project directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I am trying to set up a new project on ruby 2.5.1 and rails 5.2. The bundle is completed successfully but when I try to run any command like `rails server`, `rails db:migrate` or any other it gets killed without showing any message. [image]

I am unable to find any solution, is there any way I can check the logs that why mac is aborting the commands. Moreover, this issue is happening only with this project. all other projects are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, It was the issue with the OpenSSL libraries on Catalina, Fixed by executing the following commands

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.dylib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/libssl.dylib
```

if these commands executed without any error, everything should work.

Check the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/ritaly/9ded38e1918e55b928ff357fbdf07417)